# Failed to run EfficientNet model to trained 4 class

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, efficientnet

I'm going to train my model with 4 classes with images.

Here's my pre-trained code look like

```
conv_base = EfficientNetB0(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
                                               input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
```

I trained my mode with code like this:

```
eff_history = model.fit(
                        train_generator,
                        validation_data=validation_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=486 // 20,
                        epochs=10)
```

But there's problem occured like below:

[image: error]

Any help guys?

Comment: Post your whole model code.

Comment: here's my code bro, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18AtIP7aOycHPDR84PuQ7iS8aYUdclZIe?usp=sharing thanks for checking

Comment: Change this `model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax", name="fc_out"))` to `model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax", name="fc_out"))`. The difference is that you have 3 classes in output but you were passing 2 classes from model and hence there was a shape mismatch.

Comment: hi man, my code work for 4 class. Thanks for your help.
for further communication, may i have your email? to discuss more about this

Answer (score 1):

You have three labels for each sample, but the last layer of your model outputs 2 classes thus the number of the logits you get is 2 rather than 3. You need to change your model to have a 3 dimensional output.

Comment: is there any clue where i should change the code?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are using and whose or which implementation it is. So I can check out the source and give you better directions.

Comment: here's my code bro, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18AtIP7aOycHPDR84PuQ7iS8aYUdclZIe?usp=sharing thanks for checking

Comment: Hi can you copy the code I provided above where you define conv_base. I can not run the code at the moment.

Comment: @D.ACAR that won't be the answer to his question as your edit will make it the whole model and not the `base_model`. Also, in his code, he wants to use `Dropout` which he couldn't use otherwise. I have put the answer in the comment of the question.

Comment: Oh I see I did not notice he added some custom layers.